# cxApi.cxApi.getChosenVariation() only returns cxApi.NO_CHOSEN_VARIATION

Tags: google-analytics, content-expiration

I do the following - (`XXXXX` represent my experiment Id ) as described here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/experiments#cxjs-load

```
<!-- Google analytics Experiment-->
        <script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=XXXXX"></script> 

<script>
   var variationExperiment = cxApi.chooseVariation('XXXXX');
   cxApi.setChosenVariation(variationExperiment,'XXXXX');
   console.log(variationExperiment); // gives 0 or 1 according the google decision
   console.log(cxApi.getChosenVariation('XXXXX')); // always returns -1 , mean cxApi.NO_CHOSEN_VARIATION
</script>
```

`console.log(cxApi.getChosenVariation('XXXXX'))` only return `-1` even though I did `cxApi.setChosenVariation(variationExperiment,'XXXXX')` before .

What it is indicate ? whether my google-analytics loading didn't success ?

Answer (score 0):

chooseVariation doesn't allow any parameters. It uses the experiment from script load.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/experiments#cxjs-choose